# How to develop a magento webisite on localhost?

Tags: magento

I moved my live site in the `localhost`. Website was developed in CMS which is Magento. Now I don't know how to edit it or further develop the website. I have Magento installed on my localhost.

> Problem 1. website does not work on local-host. but the first page
>   only, all the other pages shows missing 404.
>
> Problem 2. How do I develop magento website offline on local-host?

Comment: clear session and cache (in `var` directory) and change `/app/etc/local.xml` according to your local settings and clear `log_url` tables

Comment: Thanks For the solution. I did use same solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

> website does not work on local-host. but the first page only, all the other pages shows missing 404.

The most likely cause of this is your localhost webserver does not (if it's apache) have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

> Problem 2. How do I develop magento website offline on local-host?

You develop it by editing its files!